# How to work with contacts in device only

Tags: contacts, accounts

I wanted to test custom VCF file. So I imported it in my phone to `Device` account, where was 0 contacts before (all of my contact comes from other accounts).

But When I selected `show contact from device only` in `contacts to display`, it shows me contact information merged from all other accounts and field `Connected via` shows all of these account where is this contact available.

How can I view only data stored in `Device` (to check if import is fully successful) and  be able to delete this data from device afterwards (but keep them in all other accounts)?

I'm using stock contact app on Asus ZenFone 6 (1.5.1.15_201105) which seems to be Android default.

## //Update:

1. I created `Test Contact` in Device account with phone number `123456`.
2. Then I created `Test Contact` in another account with two phone numbers `123456` and `666666`

And get this:

### Contact display settings

[image: Contact display settings]

### Contact results (there is only one contact visible)

[image: Find the contact]

### Contact detail

(notice threre is nubmer `666666` which is not part of the contact in Device account)

[image: What I see in contact]

### What I see when tap to edit icon

[image: What I see when use icon for contact edit]

This app is unintuitive mess...

Comment: From my understanding the Android contacts system simply has multiple providers. That some of them sync their contacts with a cloud in background is irrelevant for the contact system. In my device (Android 9) in the list of accounts inside the contacts app I have two entries one for the Google account and one for "Phone contacts". If I select the latter I see only the local contacts.

Comment: @Robert Yes, my previous phones did same. When filter what contacts I want to see, I saw only them. But now I see something like merged contact view (it offers me to merge some duplicate contact, but I never did it). Now I installed Simple Contacts and it behave as expected. So I was able to delete contact from Device account only.

Comment: But I still see contact image even when account where contact have images is filtered out...